How do I get auto indentation of text that is after MLA sections?
I'm trying to make an MLA template that can automatically have text that goes after sections be indented .5 inches, but even when I manually indent, nothing works.
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, BoldFont=Timesbd.ttf, ItalicFont=Timesi.ttf, BoldItalicFont=Timesbi.ttf]{Times.ttf}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{} 
    \chead{} 
    \rhead{LastName \thepage} 
    \lfoot{} 
    \cfoot{} 
    \rfoot{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\setlength\headsep{0.333in}

\newcommand{\bibent}{\noindent \hangindent 40pt}
\newenvironment{workscited}{\newpage {\centering Works Cited\par}}{\newpage }

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\refstepcounter{section}\setcounter{subsection}{0}\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}\setcounter{paragraph}{0}\setcounter{subparagraph}{0}{\textbf{\Roman{section}. #1}\par}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\refstepcounter{subsection}\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}\setcounter{paragraph}{0}\setcounter{subparagraph}{0}{\textit{\Roman{section}.\Roman{subsection}. #1}\par}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{\refstepcounter{subsubsection}\setcounter{paragraph}{0}\setcounter{subparagraph}{0}{\centering\textbf{\Roman{section}.\Roman{subsection}.\Roman{subsubsection}. #1}\par}}

\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\refstepcounter{paragraph}\setcounter{subparagraph}{0}{\centering\textit{\Roman{section}.\Roman{subsection}.\Roman{subsubsection}.\Roman{paragraph}. #1}\par}}

\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\refstepcounter{subparagraph}{\underLine{\Roman{section}.\Roman{subsection}.\Roman{subsubsection}.\Roman{paragraph}.\Roman{subparagraph}. #1}\par}}


\begin{document}
\begin{FlushLeft}

%%%%First page name, class, etc
Author\\
Teacher\\
Class\\
23 June 2024\\

\section{The Importance of Collaboration in Theatre}

Theatre is all about teamwork. Working together in theatre is super important because it brings different talents, helps creativity, and makes the show better. This makes the audience enjoy it more. This essay talks about the roles of different team members in theatre, the good and bad sides of working together, and gives examples of good teamwork in theatre.

\subsection{Roles in Collaborative Theatre}

In theatre, lots of people have to work together. Directors, actors, writers, designers, and stage managers all bring their special skills. Directors have the vision for the play and guide everyone. Actors bring the characters to life by following the script and the director's ideas. Writers create the script, which is the base of the play. Designers for sets, costumes, lights, and sound create the look and feel of the play. Stage managers and crew make sure everything runs smoothly and handle technical stuff. Each role is important, and working together is key for a good show (Gillette, 2009).

\subsubsection{Benefits and Challenges of Collaboration}

Working together in theatre has lots of benefits. It boosts creativity by mixing different ideas, leading to new and exciting solutions. Teamwork usually makes better shows because everyone adds their expertise, improving the final product. It also helps people grow personally and professionally as they learn from each other and gain new skills (Wainscott and Fletcher, 2012). But, teamwork can also be tough. Arguments can happen because of different opinions, so it's important to know how to solve conflicts. Managing everyone's schedules and resources can be hard and needs good organization. Balancing big artistic ideas with practical limits is another challenge teams have to face (Roznowski and Domer, 2016).

\paragraph{Examples of Successful Collaboration}

There are lots of examples of good teamwork in theatre. Broadway shows like "Hamilton" by Lin-Manuel Miranda show how great collaboration can be. Miranda's writing and music, along with Thomas Kail's direction and Andy Blankenbuehler's choreography, created an amazing musical. The Royal Shakespeare Company's adaptations of Shakespeare's plays show how teamwork can make old plays feel new again. Community and experimental theatres also rely a lot on teamwork, bringing different people together to make unique and powerful shows.

\subparagraph{Conclusion}

In conclusion, working together in theatre is very important because it combines different talents, boosts creativity, and makes the show better, leading to a more enjoyable experience for the audience. To encourage teamwork in theatre, it's important to have open communication, respect each other's ideas, and give everyone a chance to share their talents. By working together, theatre makers can create unforgettable experiences for the audience.

%%%%Works cited
\begin{workscited}

\bibent Gillette, Michael. \textit{The Collaborative Art of Theatre}. HarperCollins, 2009.

\bibent Roznowski, Rob, and Kirk Domer. \textit{Collaboration in Theatre: A Practical Guide for Designers and Directors}. Palgrave Macmillan, 2016.

\bibent Wainscott, Ronald J., and Kathy J. Fletcher. \textit{Theatre: Collaborative Acts}. Pearson Education, 2012.

\end{workscited}
\end{FlushLeft}

\end{document}

I am haivng trouble with having the text be auto indentned.
Is there a way i could have this be possible? I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me.

Moving the \setlength command after the \begin{document} produces the indent; although I can't say why.
